# Best way to display various information in bootstrap or other jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 images, each image has its own information and images. Not a lot, but I need it to be displayed in a pop up box. I have decided to use Bootstrap as it's responsive and quite reliable for these thing.

My question is is there any way around copy and pasting the same information, for instance, I have 10 lines of the same code just to show the modal box i.e.

```
    $("#smiley").click(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

and 200 of information etc.

Here's example http://jsfiddle.net/jjehfiuehf/0ck8y5jx/

You click image and the modal box appears.

1. The dialog box doesn't seem to appear for some reason
2. Is it ok to have a full html page full of information or is there a way to condense it somehow??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one modal and load the information dynamically from a PHP script using AJAX.

- Put all of your images, 200 (whatever) of information, etc. into a PHP script - perhaps in an array.
- In your HTML, include an ID or `data-attribute` that corresponds with the key in the array. Each one is unique.
- Create a jQuery script that parses the ID or data-attribute, and then calls the PHP script via jQuery's `.get()` method, which then loads the content into the modal body and displays it.

You could also store all of these as separate HTML documents instead of putting them into PHP, and load each file accordingly...

---

Also, there's [Varying modal content based on trigger button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) - which may be more inline to what you need

From the Bootstrap docs:

> Have a bunch of buttons that all trigger the same modal, just with slightly different contents? Use `event.relatedTarget` and `HTML data-*` attributes (possibly via jQuery) to vary the contents of the modal depending on which button was clicked.

Comment: They're both similar, just go with what works for you. I use the first method. You can find articles on getting data via jQuery all over the internet.

Comment: If this answer is sufficient, please mark as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Dialog box does not appear because of Jquery version you should use 2.1.3 on left side you have on jfiddle Frameworks & Extensions, framework can be changed.

2.it is OK to have all information in html, and if you do not want all information in html, you should use server side scripting, PHP or else.